# How to bind to multiple sources without codebehind or using SelectedValue

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

While trying to convert usual wpf fields to the custom fields that the program I need to modify, I came across an issue of having 2 different data sources.

1) The data source that retrieves/inserts data to fill this combobox (DataSource)

2) The data source that takes care of other UI elements (DSP)

As when certain items are selected from the combobox, not only does it get stored with the other information in the form, but it may show/hide another UI element.

I am trying to convert:

```
<ComboBox Name="tempComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}, Path=Value.Properties[temp].MetaData.Lookups}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
          SelectedValuePath="Value" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource DSP}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
          Style="{StaticResource tempComboStyle}"/>
```

Into something like this:

```
<ctrls:Fields Name="tempComboBox"
              FieldName="temp"
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}, Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              Style="{StaticResource tempComboStyle}"/>
```

However, this WILL NOT work as it only stores the data, but does not hide/show elements when the specific item is selected.

I have tried multi binding, which does not work. Surrounding the combobox tags with the ctrls:Fields tag, again doesn't work. And combining the DataContext property with both SelectedValue and ItemSource, none of which work.

I do not have any way of getting to the code behind of this form either, it must be strictly done through XAML.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: In `ctrls:Fields`, where do you specify the selected item? Without knowing the selected item, how cna you control it?

Comment: It is found by defining FieldName as it relates to a database item that defines what it is i.e. textbox, combobox, checkbox, etc.